# How to detect a plugin is loaded in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Is there a way to detect whether a plugin has been loaded into a WordPress page? For example, if contact form 7's plugin is loaded into page, then do some function.

Comment: Please edit question and explain what you have tried already to solve your problem, so we don't suggest the same.

Answer (score 0):

[get_plugins()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugins) does that for you.

Before calling it you might want to make sure that [all plugis are loaded](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/plugins_loaded).

To check, wether the plugin is actually active you might have to use [is_plugin_active($plugin)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active)

Good luck, and next time maybe try Google before posting a question here.